# Computer died while doing "conda update --all". Now I get an error "conda command not found". How do I get it back?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Question is pretty self-explanatory. My computer crashed (lost power) during an update to conda. Now it seems that it is all gone.

I am running on a OS X 10.10.5.

I cannot do anything with conda.

I am not tech savvy. I recently started using Python. Complete newbie.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can always do a complete reinstall of Anaconda.

Comment: delete all traces of conda and reinstall

Comment: Try to (re)install Conda. If it says it's already installed, you can use `-force`. [docs be here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#already-installed-error-message)